# What parser algorithm is best suited for command line parsing?

Tags: algorithms, command-line

I want to write my own command line library from scratch. What algorithm should I use in order to parse gnu style args like in getopt for example ? I mean what's the best way other than tokenizing and parse them in a naive way? Should I try to look at LR, LL algorithms or this is way too overkill?

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering.SE... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: The best way is to tokenize and parse in the naive way.  A simple Split function call will get you all of the top-level tokens, in most cases, and another split will separate the switches from the parameters, so compiler-level parsers are always overkill.  Most of the existing command line parsing libraries are too complicated; it's simpler just to write a naive class.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524661.  As you can see, there's plenty of prior art.

Comment: Algorithms like LR are concerned with context free grammars, i.e. recursive syntax. Command line flags don't generally feature complicated syntax, but generally only flags and key-value pairs. An ad-hoc approach is often entirely sufficient. Once you want combined flags (`-abc` = `-a -b -c`), `--foo=bar` style values, or abbreviations, then using an existing options parsing library seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

An [LL(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) parser is a top down left to right parser, that needs only to know one symbol in advance.  This is sufficient to parse a command line syntax.

But constructing an LL(1) parser seems to be an overkill for this kind of tasks, where a loop, a couple of `if`s and some flags would completely do the trick.